# Python importing own lib thats import files

Tags: python, import, lib

I wrote a Reusable_script.py script that I will use quite often in various other scripts, it is in the C:\SCRIPTS directory so I added it to the PATH.

I created a test file test.py in another directory and import the previous one as:

`import Reusable_script`

but this script reads the files that are with it in a directory ('file1.csv'), but when I import it into a script that is in a different directory I get an error that the file is not found. How to make imported libraries look for a file in their directory and the one they are added to.

```
C:\
   = SCRIPT
      |
        - Reusable_script.py
        - file1.csv
    = WORK
          - test.py
```

Comment: You need to use the `PYTHONPATH` variable for this, which will provide python with another path to search for imports. `PATH` is how the shell finds executables.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best practice to pass the directory to search as an argument.

For example:

```py
# reusable_script.py
from pathlib import Path

def foo(directory: Path) -> List[Path]:
    return [child for child in directory.iterdir()]
```

You could then call this like so:

```py
# my_script.py
from pathlib import Path
from reusable_script import foo

def bar():
    my_path = Path("/home/alex/baz/")
    return foo(my_path)
```